# Configure Gradle's Artifactory plugin to publish to release or snapshot repository

Tags: gradle, artifactory

Artifactory have two pre-defined repositories for local libraries:

- `libs-release-local`: local repository for in-house libraries
- `libs-snapshot-local`: local repository for in-house snapshots

The Artifactory's Gradle script generator can generate a script which uses only one repository for artifact publishing, using the `artifactory` plugin for Gradle.

Here is an example (only the relevant portion):

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
}
```

I would like to configure the plugin to use the `libs-release-local` or `libs-snapshot-local` repository based on version (i.e. if version ends with `-SNAPSHOT` then publish to `libs-snapshot-local`).

I saw this is possible using Gradle's integrated `maven` plugin (see `snapshotRepository` element of `mavenDeployer` in `uploadArchives` task), but this functionality seems not available in the `artifactory` plugin.

Is there any way to achieve this desired behaviour?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since it's a groovy *code* just go ahead and use a variable, which depends on the version.

```
String repo = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? 'libs-snapshot-local' : 'libs-release-local'
```

...

```
repository {
        repoKey = repo
        username = "${artifactory_user}"
        password = "${artifactory_password}"
        maven = true

    }
```